# How to draw a line behind an alpha region in matplotlb?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib seems to always draw a line plot in front of an alpha shaded region, whereas I want to achieve the opposite.

Minimal Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axhline(0.5, color="red")
plt.axvspan(0, 1, ymin=0, ymax=1, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

The code above produces the image below. You can clearly see that the line is drawn in front of the alpha region.

[A red line in front of a blue alpha shaded region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFPXq.png)

Is there a way to draw it behind the alpha region?